# Ring of integers with prime numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p \in \mathbb{N}$ be an odd prime.
a) Investigate the value of $[(p-1)!]_p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$
b) Investigate the value of $\big[\big(\frac{p-1}{2}!\big)^2\big]_p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

$\mathbb{Z}$ is the integers. How do I do this question? I know $p-1$ is going to be even so it wont be a prime anymore.

Comment: By $[n]_p$ you mean the class of $n$ in $\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z p$?

Comment: [n]_p={x is an integer|x is congruent to nmodp}

Comment: You might want to look at values for small $p$.

Comment: is Z_p={0,1,2,3,...,p-1}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Wilson's theorem to conclude that $(p-1)!\equiv -1$ in $\mathbb Z_p$
Lets do it.
Consider $\mathbb Z_p$ a finite integral domain and hence a field.Consider the equation $x^2=1$  in $\mathbb Z_p$.then either $x-1=0$ or $x+1=0$.Thus $x=1$ or $x=p-1$.Thus 1 and p-1 are only elements which are inverse of themselves..the other elements can be paired in such a way that they are inverses of each other.so $2.3....p-2=1$ multiplying both sides by p-1 so that $(p-1)!=p-1=-1 $ in $\mathbb Z_p$

Comment: I have never heard of this theorem... is there another way.

Comment: Shall I give the proof

Comment: can you do it without the use of a theorem please.

Comment: You can call them what you want, but *to prove* something you use theorems, claims, propositions, etc., i.e. true statements under certain assumptions. And here **you need** to prove Wilson's Theorem. The proof is pretty easy using group theory, for example.

Comment: where did u get x=p-1 from?

Comment: x=1 or x=-1; x=-1 will imply x=p-1

Comment: I don't get it... its not obvious in my eyes

Comment: is it clear@snowman

Comment: it reaaaally isn't. probably because im stupid

Comment: consider $\mathbb Z_p,-1$ will belong to the same class as -1+p which is definition of an equivalence class clear $a$ and $b$ will belong to the same class iff a-b=pk for some k

Comment: Now clear@snowman